Sweep and Prune algorithm performance
I just managed to implement my Sweep and Prune algorithm together with AABB and it's working correctly in the first axis (I haven't implemented second and third yet to complete the collision detection).
However the performance is somewhat lacking. I get 20FPS with 1000 rendered objects.
Any help would be much appreciated. (Sorry for the large amount of code.) Feel free to ask any questions whatsoever! I'm very new to C++ so there's probably lot's of things that doesn't make sense.
The last function findOverlap() is the main "Sweep and Prune"-function.
A quick summary of the algorithm:
`

Update all the Edges positions as the objects/entities move around in the game world
Calculate the variance of each axis to find which axis to begin with
Being with the axis that has the largest variance
Sort selected Axis by coordinates using insertion sort
Sweep and Prune (copied from pseudocode here: https://leanrada.com/notes/sweep-and-prune-2/)
`

Called in main-loop each frame
// Sweep and Prune
updateEdgePos(meshList, allEdgesX, allEdgesY, allEdgesZ);

float varianceX = calculateVariance(allEdgesX);
float varianceY = calculateVariance(allEdgesY);
float varianceZ = calculateVariance(allEdgesZ);

std::vector<Edge>* selectedEdges = findMaxVarianceAxis(varianceX, varianceY, varianceZ, allEdgesX, allEdgesY, allEdgesZ);

insertionSort(*selectedEdges);

std::vector<std::vector<int>> collisionCouples = findOverlap(*selectedEdges);

struct Edge {} (each Entity/Object has six of these: minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ)
struct Edge {
    int id;         // id to identify which entity it belongs to
    bool isLeft;
    float coord;

    Edge(int id, bool isLeft, float coord)
        : id(id), isLeft(isLeft), coord(coord) {}
};

updateEdgePos()
void updateEdgePos(const std::vector<Mesh>& meshList, std::vector<Edge>& allEdgesX, std::vector<Edge>& allEdgesY, std::vector<Edge>& allEdgesZ)
{
    for (Edge& edge : allEdgesX)
    {
        if (edge.isLeft)
            edge.coord = meshList[edge.id].edgesList[0].coord;
        else
            edge.coord = meshList[edge.id].edgesList[1].coord;
    }
    for (Edge& edge : allEdgesY)
    {
        if (edge.isLeft)
            edge.coord = meshList[edge.id].edgesList[2].coord;
        else
            edge.coord = meshList[edge.id].edgesList[3].coord;
    }
    for (Edge& edge : allEdgesZ)
    {
        if (edge.isLeft)
            edge.coord = meshList[edge.id].edgesList[4].coord;
        else
            edge.coord = meshList[edge.id].edgesList[5].coord;
    }
}

calculateVariance()
float calculateVariance(const std::vector<Edge>& edges) {
    // Step 1: Calculate the mean (average)
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (Edge edge : edges) {
        sum += edge.coord;
    }
    float mean = sum / edges.size();

    // Step 2: Calculate the sum of squared differences from the mean
    float sumSquaredDiffs = 0.0;
    for (Edge edge : edges) {
        float diff = edge.coord - mean;
        sumSquaredDiffs += diff * diff;
    }

    // Step 3: Calculate the variance (divide by the number of elements)
    float variance = sumSquaredDiffs / edges.size();

    return variance;
}

findMaxVariance()
std::vector<Edge>* findMaxVarianceAxis(const float& varianceX, const float& varianceY, const float& varianceZ, std::vector<Edge>& allEdgesX, std::vector<Edge>& allEdgesY, std::vector<Edge>& allEdgesZ)
{
    std::vector<Edge>* selectedEdges;
    if ((varianceX > varianceY) and (varianceX > varianceZ))
        selectedEdges = &allEdgesX;
    else if ((varianceY > varianceX) and (varianceY > varianceZ))
        selectedEdges = &allEdgesY;
    else
        selectedEdges = &allEdgesZ;

    return selectedEdges;
}

insertionSort()
void insertionSort(std::vector<Edge>& edges) {
    for (int i = 1; i < edges.size(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            if (edges[j].coord < edges[j + 1].coord) break;
                std::swap(edges[j], edges[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}

findOverlap()
std::vector<std::vector<int>> findOverlap(const std::vector<Edge>& edges)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> currentTouching;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> collisionCouplesList;

    for (const Edge& edge : edges)
    {
        if (edge.isLeft)
        {
            for (int touchingId : currentTouching)
            {
                collisionCouplesList.push_back({ edge.id, touchingId });
            }
            currentTouching.insert(edge.id);
        }
        else
        {
            currentTouching.erase(edge.id);
        }
    }

    return collisionCouplesList;
}


You should be profiling different parts of the function to see where the majority of time is spent; once you have narrowed it down, if you still can't solve it yourself, you can post that part here so that others don't have to guess at which part of your code is slow.

Ok thanks for the tip! I have never done profiling in C++ before, mind pointing me in the right direction? :)
